# Integrating R in QGIS with Mac OS El Captain: missing dependencies

Tags: qgis, r, installation, mac

I have a Mac OS (El Captain) and I'm trying to run R scripts within QGIS 2.14. When I open a script (like one from the online list) I receive the error message:

> This algorithm cannot be run :-( 
>   This algorithm requires R to be run. Unfortunately, it seems that R is not installed in your system, or it is not correctly configured to be used from QGIS 
>   Click here to know more about how to install and configure R to be used with QGIS

Please note that:

1. R is correctly installed
2. I followed instructions from http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/R-in-QGIS-on-OSX-using-Kyngchaos-build-td5254567.html
3. It is not possible to set the R folder, as I did in Windows (see the figure here below), but only the R script folder.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the problem following these steps:

- open the Terminal, digit `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile` and add two rows:

  *export R_HOME=“/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources”
  export PYTHONPATH="/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python"*

  save the file and close the Terminal
- open a new Terminal digit `sudo nano /etc/paths`

  enter your password when prompted

  Go to the bottom of the file, and enter the path you wish to add (in my case was */Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources*).

  Hit control-x to quit.

  Enter “Y” to save the modified buffer.
- copying the two link files (R and Rscripts) that are in "/usr/local/bin" folder and pasting to "/usr/bin".
- Restart your MAC

;)

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 1):

OSX 10.13, R 3.4.3, QGIS 2.18.2, GDAL 2.1.2 Python 2.7
I just solved the problem like above:

1. open the Terminal, type

   > nano ~/.bash_profile
2. add two rows:

   ```
   export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources 
   export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
   ```
3. save the file and close the Terminal
4. open a new Terminal digit

   > sudo nano /etc/paths

   enter your password when prompted
   Go to the bottom of the file, and enter

   > /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources

   Hit control-x to quit.
   Enter “Y” to save the modified buffer.
5. copying the two link files (R and Rscript) that are in "/usr/local/bin" folder and pasting to "/usr/bin". Pay attention to the version of the R.Framework. Open a terminal window and type

   > sudo cp /usr/local/bin/R  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/bin
   >
   > cp /usr/local/bin/Rscript /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/bin
6. Restart OSX

Answer (score 1):

Either one of these solutions posted above work, but there is a critical missing bit of information. You need to disable the System Integrity Protection feature in El Capitan as per [this link](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-turn-off-mac-os-x-system-integrity-protection-rootless-3638975/). Once you disable the SIP, you can copy the R and Rscript link files from "/usr/local/bin" folder to "/usr/bin". It worked for me after about 24 hours of frustration and now I can run R scripts in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Mac Os X is an Unix system and the processing Python module search for an R executable because it uses the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to execute the script directly with R.

The Python script involved is `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/r/RUtils.py`

1) it search for the R executable
2) it creates a R script with the command that should be executed (`/.../.qgis2/processing/processing_script.r)`
3) it executes `R processing_script.r`  with the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module

Therefore, if you can launch R from the terminal  (Terminal.app), no problem, you have nothing to do.

[image]

If not, try in the Terminal.app

```
which R
```

- In Yosemite the result is `/usr/bin/R` with an R executable witch is a symbolic link  of `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.x/Resources/bin/R`
- In El Capitan the result is `/usr/local/bin/R` because of the [System Integrity Protection (SIP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection), [About System Integrity Protection on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (you cannot use `/usr/bin/`, amongst other things, only Apple is allowed to install software under `/usr/bin` . `/usr/local/bin` is for the others)

Look at [[Qgis-user] R in QGIS on OSX using Kyngchaos build](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2016-March/035610.html)

Simply add PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH" in your .bash_profile file (search in /usr/local/bin/ before /usr/bin/)

Comment: It did not solve the issue